# Kapt + LoganSquare not working propertly on mapping

Tags: android, json, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, parcel

I'm using the Kotlin to build my application for Android. Then I choose the LoganSquare library to do the parse from JSON -> Object.

After some work, I get this result:

```
@JsonObject
class Line(@PrimaryKey @JsonField var id : Int,
            @JsonField var name : String) : Parcelable {

  companion object {
    @JsonIgnore @JvmField final val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Line> =
      object : Parcelable.Creator<Line> {
      override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): Line = Line(source)
      override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Line?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
  }

  constructor(parcel : Parcel) : this(parcel.readInt(), parcel.readString())

  override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flag: Int) {
    parcel.writeInt(id)
    parcel.writeString(name)
  }

  override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

}
```

After the build, the processor of LoganSquare needs to bind every field, but the kapt returns this:

[image: sample]

Look for the generated code (on the right), this is incorrect. This issue was generated by a error on LoganSquare or kapt? Can you help me to solve this problem?

- Kotlin: 1.0.1-2
- LoganSquare: 1.3.6
- Gradle: 2.10